# PHP Mysql prepare query sort according with date

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

trying to sort out according with date in prepare statement.

DISTINCT date query

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT match_date FROM premier_league
                    WHERE match_date >= :current_date
                    AND pre_selected = :pre_selected
                    ORDER BY match_date LIMIT 5');


                $stmt-> execute(array('current_date' => $current_date,
                        'pre_selected' => $pre_selected));

                $row_count_date = $stmt->rowCount();

                    $row_match_date = $stmt->fetchAll();

                    foreach ($row_match_date as $row) {

                        echo $row['match_date']."<br>\n";
                    }
```

Result
2013-07-11
2013-07-12
2013-07-15

And query based on the DISTINCT date query

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT match_id, LEFT (match_time, 5)  match_time, 
                    home_team, away_team, pre_selected, my_choice FROM premier_league
                    WHERE match_date >= :match_date
                    AND pre_selected = :pre_selected
                    ORDER BY match_time, home_team LIMIT 5');

                $stmt-> execute(array('match_date' => $current_date,
                        'pre_selected' => $pre_selected));

                $row_count_match = $stmt->rowCount();

                    $row_match = $stmt->fetchAll();

                    foreach ($row_match as $row) {

                        echo $row['match_id']."<br>\n";
                    }
```

Result
680
681
682

what I am looking the output should be the following format.

2013-07-11
680
2013-07-12
681
2013-07-15
682
Old way I am done this but prepare statement confusing...

Comment: Neither mysqli nor prepared statements has nothing to do with sorting.

Comment: I'm trying to write a code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT match_date FROM premier_league
                WHERE match_date >= :current_date
                AND pre_selected = :pre_selected
                ORDER BY match_date LIMIT 5');


            $stmt-> execute(array('current_date' => $current_date,
                    'pre_selected' => $pre_selected));

            $row_count_date = $stmt->rowCount();

                $row_match_date = $stmt->fetchAll();

                foreach ($row_match_date as $row) {

                    $dates[] = $row['match_date'];
                }
```

I have create an array with match_date. Now I will do the same for the next match_id:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT match_id, LEFT (match_time, 5)  match_time, 
                home_team, away_team, pre_selected, my_choice FROM premier_league
                WHERE match_date >= :match_date
                AND pre_selected = :pre_selected
                ORDER BY match_time, home_team LIMIT 5');

            $stmt-> execute(array('match_date' => $current_date,
                    'pre_selected' => $pre_selected));

            $row_count_match = $stmt->rowCount();

                $row_match = $stmt->fetchAll();

                foreach ($row_match as $row) {

                    $ids[] = $row['match_id'];
                }
```

Now, we have two arrays $ids (with match_id inside) and $dates (with match_date inside). So we will show in our like order.

```
      $i = 0;
      foreach($ids as $id) {
      echo $dates[$i];
      echo "<br/>";
      echo $id;
      echo "<br/>";
      $i++;   
      }
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: I'm happy to help you! God bless you!